# HTAccess 'Mirror Domain', respecting SSL, respecting co.uk+.com, keeping subdomain and request_uri

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to map multiple domains onto a main one for SEO and simplicity purposes.

My three domains are

```
webdevguru.co.uk
t3chguy.co.uk
mortie.org
```

I want both of the example domains to get redirected to the main domain, keeping their subdomain and the file and query string the client accessed.

For example:

```
str.webdevguru.co.uk => str.webdevguru.co.uk/
webdevguru.co.uk     => www.webdevguru.co.uk/
fusion.t3chguy.co.uk => fusion.webdevguru.co.uk/
mortie.org/foo?bar   => www.webdevguru.co.uk/foo?bar
https://mortie.org/  => https://www.webdevguru.co.uk/
```

Basically, I want ALL traffic redirected to the main domain, this also has to respect HTTPS as the domain cms gets transferred to a different URL, my subfolder containing the cms subdirectory files has the following code in the .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cms\.webdevguru\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://secure24447.qnop.net/~t3chguy/tools/cms%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This second code works absolutely fine I am just showing it to further explain my example. I keep having issues with any regex I keep trying, it works in one way but not in another, could some people please suggest what I could do to get the above functionality?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I give it a try :

```
# simple rule to redirect mainexample.co.uk to www.mainexample.co.uk
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^\.]+\.(com|co\.uk|org)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mainexample.co.uk/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]

# same, with HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^\.]+\.(com|co\.uk|org)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mainexample.co.uk/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]

# here comes the funny part
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC] # no HTPPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.(.+)\.(com|co\.uk|org) [NC] # capture the subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !mainexample\.co\.uk$ [NC] # we are not on mainexample.co.uk
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.mainexample.co.uk/$1 [R=301,QSA,L] # 301 redirection to mainexample keeping the subdomain and the request uri

# same, for HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.(.+)\.(com|co\.uk|org) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !mainexample\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1.mainexample.co.uk/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

There no need to duplicate rules for http and https, but I don't know how to do one only rule.

---

Edit regarding your HTTPS issue :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(cms|fusion)\.[^\.]+\.(com|co\.uk|org)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://secure27.qnop.net/~t3chguy/%1/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Comment: ### qoo.example1.co.uk => http://qoo.example1.co.mainexample.co.uk/
### qoo.mainexample.co.uk => qoo.mainexample.co.uk {FUNCTIONAL}
### Not working with empty subdomains? You sure, works fine for me... Which is strange since you said it wouldn't work.

Comment: Works perfectly except if the folder doesn't exist it doesn't redirect to the domain anyway, is that a possibility;
Like: t3chguy.co.uk/?foobar WORKS
Whereas: t3chguy.co.uk/foobar Does Not.

Comment: Well, I don't see the reason why it doesn't work with a folder attached. You mean t3chguy.co.uk/?foobar redirects correctly to www.mainexample.co.uk/?foobar but t3chguy.co.uk/foobar does not redirect at all ?

Comment: I guess it's because you have no subdomain. I have updated my answer, give it a try now.

Comment: Works great except webdevguru.co.uk [mainexample.co.uk] does not redirect to www.webdevguru.co.uk

Comment: Oh, that does not sound logic to me oO What about mortie.org, is it redirecting to www.webdevguru.co.uk ?

Comment: T3chguy.co.uk and other secondary domains redirect to www.webdevguru.co.uk

Comment: I don't think this is a regex problem any more, have you anything left in your .htaccess from a previous test ? There is no reason T3chguy.co.uk redirects well but not webdevguru.co.uk...

Comment: It seems to work great, must have been browser cache; should have been using 302 redirects for testing.

Comment: I need a slight change, I am on shared hosting, I cannot use https on my actual domain; therefore do not need the HTTPS rules as webdevguru.co.uk will never be used alongside https. To access my site via HTTPS I have to use this as the base URI: https://secure27.qnop.net/~t3chguy/
Could you add functionality for some predefined subdomains to redirect to https://secure27.qnop.net/~t3chguy/%{SUBDOMAIN}?%{QUERY}
The only sub-domain which is currently in need of SSL/HTTPS is [cms].webdevguru.co.uk

Comment: well since https://webdevguru.co.uk doesn't ever reach my webroot; I need certain subdomains (cms|fusion) to be redirected to https://secure27.qnop.net/~t3chguy/%{SUBDOMAIN}?%{QUERY}

Comment: I have edited my answer, but I'm not sure what you mean by %{QUERY}, I suppose it's the folder and the page of the requested URI

Comment: Folder, page, query string; /folder/file.php?querystring

Comment: That fix is almost perfect, but for some reason cms.t3chguy.co.uk or cms.webdevguru.co.uk redirect to https://secure27.qnop.net/~t3chguy/cms?tools/cms/ instead of https://secure27.qnop.net/~t3chguy/cms?

Comment: Where is it getting the tools/cms bit from .co.uk/ has no query at the end of it so I don't know where its appearing from, tools/cms is actually the current location of the cms which is even stranger...

Comment: I correct my answer, I was not sure of what you wanted that's why I used a ? instead of a /. Now should be fine, there is no need to add the query string as the flag [QSA] will pass it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cms\.mainexample\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://secure24447.qnop.net/~t3chguy/tools/cms%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.webdevguru\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^webdevguru\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?mortie\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.webdevguru.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.[^.]+\.[^.]+\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1.webdevguru.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: ### qoo.example.co.uk redirected to www.mainexample.co.uk
    ### qoo.mainexample.co.uk redirected to .mainexample.co.uk

Comment: feel free to test it, qoo.t3chguy.co.uk redirects to www.webdevguru.co.uk
qoo.webdevguru.co.uk is a non-existent domain but I have the * subdomain pointed at my public_html and this is functional prior to your script above, thanks anyway; I'd love if you managed to fix it but thanks for trying.

Comment: Did you ever mention `webdevguru` before anywhere in question? Specify all the requirement clearly in question first then come back to testing.

Comment: webdevguru.uk is mainexample
t3chguy.co.uk is example1
I have some other domains, both .com and .co.uk but those above are the main ones.

Comment: Ok then obviously example strings need to be replaced from question since you didn't provide all the correct domain names.

Comment: It would be better if you provide all real domains instead of example ones to get some clarity in answer.

Comment: I changed them to real domains, basically I want all traffic on the main one so the other two should not be listed in the .htaccess as I need it dynamic to however many domains I have.